# TCPDF / FPDF - Page break issue

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdf

I'm trying to create a PDF file with a table of data.. But when a page break is met it jumps to a new page everytime a new multicell is added to the page at the break point level..!?

I have tried to do exactly the same with TCPDF, but still the same issue with a page break each time a new cell i added around the page break point level...

example:

[http://www.online-økonomi.dk/_tst_fpdf.php](http://www.online-%C3%B8konomi.dk/_tst_fpdf.php)

```
require_once '../class/download/fpdf/fpdf.php';

class File_PDF {
    private $pdf;

    private $col_product = 25;
    private $col_unit = 12;
    private $col_price = 20;
    private $col_count = 14;
    private $col_discount = 12;
    private $col_vat = 12;
    private $col_sum = 22;

    private $width = 200;
    private $line_height = 4.2;
    private $margin_top = 30;

    public function generate(){
        $this->pdf = new FPDF();
        $this->pdf->AddPage();
        $this->pdf->SetDisplayMode('real');
        $this->pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 150);

        if($this->products){
            $i = 0;
            $this->color_light();
            foreach($this->products as $product){
                $this->add_product($product, $i % 2 ? true:false);
                $i++;
            }
        }

        $this->pdf->Output();
    }

    private function add_product($product, $fill){
        $this->txt();

        $x = $this->width;
        $y = $this->pdf->GetY();

        $this->cell_sum($this->col_sum, $x, $y, $product['sum'] / 100, 'R', $fill);
        $this->cell_vat($this->col_vat, $x, $y, $product['vat_percent'], 'R', $fill);
        $this->cell_discount($this->col_discount, $x, $y, $product['discount_percent'] / 100, 'R', $fill);
        $this->cell_count($this->col_count, $x, $y, $product['count'] / 100, 'R', $fill);
        $this->cell_price($this->col_price, $x, $y, $product['price'] / 100, 'R', $fill);
        $this->cell_unit($this->col_unit, $x, $y, $product['unit_name'], 'L', $fill);
        $this->cell_name(0, $x, $y, $product['name'], 'L', $fill);
        $this->cell_product($this->col_product, $x, $y, $product['product_id_'], 'L', $fill);
    }

    private function cell_sum($width, &$x, $y, $str, $align, $fill=false){
        $this->cnstr_cell($width, $x, $y, $str, $align, $fill);
    }

    private function cell_vat($width, &$x, $y, $str, $align, $fill=false){
        $this->cnstr_cell($width, $x, $y, $str, $align, $fill);
    }

    private function cell_discount($width, &$x, $y, $str, $align, $fill=false){
        $this->cnstr_cell($width, $x, $y, $str, $align, $fill);
    }

    private function cell_count($width, &$x, $y, $str, $align, $fill=false){
        $this->cnstr_cell($width, $x, $y, $str, $align, $fill);
    }

    private function cell_price($width, &$x, $y, $str, $align, $fill=false){
        $this->cnstr_cell($width, $x, $y, $str, $align, $fill);
    }

    private function cell_unit($width, &$x, $y, $str, $align, $fill=false){
        $this->cnstr_cell($width, $x, $y, $str, $align, $fill);
    }

    private function cell_name($width, &$x, $y, $str, $align, $fill=false){
        $this->pdf->SetXY($this->col_product + 10, $y);
        $this->pdf->MultiCell($x - $this->col_product - 10, $this->line_height, $str, 0, $align, $fill);
    }

    private function cell_product($width, &$x, $y, $str, $align, $fill=false){
        $this->pdf->SetXY(10, $y);
        $this->pdf->MultiCell($this->col_product, $this->line_height, $str, 0, $align, $fill);
    }

    private function cnstr_cell($width, &$x, $y, $str, $align='L', $fill=false){
        $x -= $width;
        $this->pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
        $this->pdf->MultiCell($width, $this->line_height, $str, 0, $align, $fill);
    }

    private function color_light(){
        $this->pdf->SetFillColor(200, 200, 200);
    }

    private function txt(){
        $this->pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8.5);
    }

    private function txt_marked(){
        $this->pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8.5);
    }

    private $products = array(
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            ),
        array(
            'product_id_' => 'ADS1550',
            'name' => 'name',
            'unit_name' => 'pcs',
            'price' => 182450000,
            'count' => 310000,
            'discount_percent' => 19900,
            'vat_percent' => 0,
            'sum' => 1587057200
            )
        );
}

$PDF = new File_PDF();
$PDF->generate();
```

Comment: Could you please give a *short* code sample? Just take 10 minutes to simplify your code so that it fills in one page, remove all the object properties, and more people may try to answer you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that in the `Cell()` method (which is called in `MultiCell()`) FPDF allways adds a new page if the the current Y position + the height of the new cell is greater than the allowed page height.

The default page height seems to be 297, with `SetAutoPageBreak()` you substract `150` from it. So when `Y` + `cell_height` is graeter than 147 you allways get a new page when calling your `cnstr_cell()`.

To prevent this you need to call `AddPage()` by yourself. Add this check in your `add_product()` method:

```
$x = $this->width;
$y = $this->pdf->GetY();

if (($y + $this->line_height) >= 147) {
    $this->pdf->AddPage();
    $y = 0; // should be your top margin
}
```

Btw. I also had to generate a dynamic PDF recently, I ended up using [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), it was way more easy to use and customize than all the PHP libraries. I suggest to take a look at it.

Comment: Just an FYi, while reading this answer today, I noticed the link to `wkhtmltopdf` is broken.