# MultiCell page break in fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I am creating a table using multicell in fpdf,the problem is that after the first page each new cell I add goes to a new page.i found a similar problem [TCPDF / FPDF - Page break issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334514/tcpdf-fpdf-page-break-issue) but i was not able to understand the solution

Answer (score -1):

That depends on the exact dimensions of those cells, but you could try these (see Links below for the respective description in the TCPDF documentation):

Disable auto page break:

```
$tcpdf->setPageOrientation("P", false);
```

Set $reseth false in the Mutlicell call:

```
$tcpdf->MultiCell(60, 30, "Text", 0, 'J', $fill = false,
    $ln = 1, $x = '', $y = '',
    $reseth = true);
```

If these are not working, you could also try hard-setting the XY Coordinates of the Multicell by using:

```
$tcpdf->SetXY(30, 50);
```

- [TCPDF class documentation](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/)

Comment: Links are broken

Comment: I have corrected the link(s) and posted the new link to the class documentation.