# barryvdh/laravel-dompdf check if page is broken?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf-generation, dompdf, barryvdh

I am using `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`. I want to know that is there any way to find that the page is fully populated and the content goes to the next page? The documentation mentions the page break event by CSS

```
<style>
.page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
<h1>Page 1</h1>
<div class="page-break"></div>
<h1>Page 2</h1>
```

But my problem is to actually know exactly when the page is fully populated.

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334514/tcpdf-fpdf-page-break-issue

Comment: It's good but the library is different. I'm checking if it's valid in the current library or not